How to get around the 'configure: error: unrecognized option: `-''
I recently decided to sync OneDrive to my Windows machine. I have a virtual environment where I run molecular dynamics simulations using AMBER source code (Ubuntu). The source code file path was changed (because I sync'd OneDrive) and now everything is screwed up because of the '-' and spaces in the OneDrive folder name. I want to get around the 'configure: error: unrecognized option: '-'' error because I need to reconfigure openmpi to run AMBER MD in parallel. I have tried a few solutions, including putting '' after each word, and putting the file path in quotations. These solutions have helped to correctly source the file path in my bash shell, but I cannot complete the OpenMPI configuration step, because it does not like the '-'....if someone could suggest another work-around, that would be very helpful
Error provided below:
(base) oliviameyer@Liv:/mnt/c/Users/LivMeyer/OneDrive - University of Cincinnati/Desktop/amber22_src/AmberTools/src$ ./configure_openmpi gnu
Installing openMPI in /mnt/c/Users/LivMeyer/OneDrive - University of Cincinnati/Desktop/amber22
openmpi-4.1.5/
configure: error: unrecognized option: -' Try ./configure --help' for more information
openmpi configure failed, returning 1
ALSO the './configure --help' tells me that the directory is not where I should complete the configuration, BUT I already know that this the correct directory to complete the configuration, as I have ALREADY done this previously.

Probably the simplest solution is to move the source tree of the program that you are trying to build into a location whose name doesn't contain whitespace - there are likely going to be other issues associated with building on a mounted Windows drive anyhow
